# How to include Angular (not JS) types in tsconfig so I don't have to import them?

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I've been spending the past couple of days trying to figure out how to include Angular types in my `.d.ts` files so I don't have to import my types into other files. I tried installing `@types/angular` but quickly discovered that's for AngularJS which I don't want. For instance, if I want to define a type like this:

```
interface Foo {
   bar: EventEmitter<string>;
}
```

I would have to import `EventEmitter` and now have to export `Foo` which breaks the `.d.ts` file. Now that means it requires me to import `Foo` into whatever file I want to use it in. Instead, I would like to do something like this:

```
interface Foo {
   bar: angular.EventEmitter<string>;
}
```

Hopefully this all makes sense and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something to try: `bar: import('@angular/core').EventEmitter<string>;`

Comment: Ughh, I can't believe it was that easy!! That seems to have done the trick. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inline imports by using the following syntax:

```
import('@angular/core').EventEmitter<string>;
```

Like this:

```
interface Foo {
   bar: import('@angular/core').EventEmitter<string>;
}
```

Comment: It's not the prettiest solution but it gets the job done!